# Is there any alternative to add IAM role to my Running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

How to add IAM Role to Running Instance ? I know that that's one is not possible using Console, but is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an IAM role to your instance using the following workaround:

- Create an AMI for your instance;
- Terminate your old instance;
- Re-deploy it again from previously created AMI and assing an IAM role during the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an IAM (Identity and Access Management) **Role** to an Amazon EC2 instance is a way of securely providing rotating credentials to applications running on an EC2 instance. Such roles must be assigned **when the instance is first launched**.

If the instance you would like to use has already been launched, either:

- Launch a new instance ("Launch More Like This") with a Role, or
- Create a User in IAM: You will receive an Access Key and Secret Key that can be configured in the instance by using the `aws configure` command. This is part of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

See documentation: [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)